react.js can't connect to websocket from spring boot application
I created a little spring boot server with
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
</dependency>

having a WebSocketConfigurer
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new ServerWebSocketHandler(), "/socket");
}

and in the ServerWebSocketHandler
@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    log.info("Connection open");

    TextMessage message = new TextMessage("initial message from server");
    log.info("Sending message: {}", message);
    session.sendMessage(message);
}

When I use Postman to create a websocket connection to ws://localhost:8080/socket, the connection is established and I'm seeing the expected messages and log entries.
However, trying to establish the connection from within a react.js application fails.
This is from the App.tsx:
function App() {
  const ws : MutableRefObject<WebSocket|null> = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/socket");
    ws.current.onopen = () => console.log("ws open");
    ws.current.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");

    const wsCurrent = ws.current;

    return () => {
      wsCurrent.close();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ws.current) return;

    ws.current.onmessage = e => {
      const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log("e", message);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div>
        Hey world.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

and the log entries:
App.tsx:15 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
App.tsx:10 ws closed
App.tsx:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket' failed: 
(anonymous) @ App.tsx:8
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23189
invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:25193
invokeEffectsInDev @ react-dom.development.js:27390
commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:27369
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27095
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:27023
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26808
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533

There's nothing in the server logs from these attempts...
So why can Postman connect to the server while react fails? What am I missing?
Edit: Digging a little deeper, I noticed that the request from react fails with a 403 Forbidden...
But I fail to see the what makes one request fail and the other one succed..
GET /socket HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: -----------------------==
DNT: 1
Sec-GPC: 1
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: websocket
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket

(websocket key removed)

So the problem was that the react.js request triggered cors in the spring-boot application while the postman request ommitted the origin header and thus skipped the cors check.
For now I changed my WebSocketConfigurer to
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new ServerWebSocketHandler(), "/socket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
}

avoiding the issue.
